# Changing a variable name

Tags: java, variables

So I'm making a simple game in java. In this game I want there to be an infinite number of players.

The game is Dictionary, but not the one where you race to find a word in a dictionary.

How to play:

1. A person chooses a word that no one would know.
2. Everyone enters a made up definition that is believable.
3. Each person guesses which one is the real definition.
4. You get a point for guessing correctly and for the number of people who guess your word

(Steps 2 and 3 are ignored by the person who chooses a word)

My program (So far):

1. Choose start or quit
2. When start is pressed the number of players selected (Not including word selector).
3. Word selector chooses word in JPasswordField
4. Enters definition in JPasswordField
5. The word is told to Player 1 and then they must enter a definition into a JPasswordField
6. Repeats step 5 until the times repeated are equal to the number of players.

The problem I'm having:

```
Player + numberrepeated = passwordfield.getText;
```

doesnt exist.

I need to have the variable change each time.

Comment: Code is better than English.

Comment: Please use a better title. _Infinite variable loop_ A variable can't loop.

Comment: Well that would be because I'm first language welsh.

Comment: It seems like all people do is judge the quality of my question instead of answering it!

Comment: @user2921254 **Please.** Read carefully your question and you'll see that there is no information at all to help you. Include valid code and then maybe we will able to help.

Comment: What dont you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have dynamic variable names in Java. What you can do is use a Map, to associate a key (the player's name, for example), with a value (the player's password, for example):

```
Map<String, String> passwordsByPlayer = new HashMap<>();
...
passwordsByPlayer.put(playerName, passwordField.getText());
```

Comment: How would I change this after each loop? As in; during loop 1 map passwordfield.getText to player 1, loop 2: map to player 2, and so on.

Comment: I don't know. I can't see your loop because you haven't posted it.